# concatinate string with jinja variable

Tags: html, jinja2

i'm trying to sand some data from one html to another with "include ... with"
like that:

```
{% include 'Discret/buttons/modal.html' with type="teacher" id=teacher.id %}
```

how can i concatinate "teacher" and teacher.id in one string?
i've tried to do it with tilda~

```
{% include 'Discret/buttons/modal.html' with type="teacher"~teacher.id %}
```

and with plus+

```
{% include 'Discret/buttons/modal.html' with type="teacher"+teacher.id %}
```

and with convert function

```
{% include 'Discret/buttons/modal.html' with type="teacher"+teacher.id|string %}
```

but nothing works.

Comment: this looks fishy `type="teacher"+teacher.id` as you have only 1 set of quotes. Those end after teacher. I think jinja wont read further.  I think if anything they all need to be inside those quotes. `type="teacher{{teacher.id}}"` something like this, I dont really know jina, so not sure if double curly braces are correct, but you get the idea.

Comment: Try this, pass your teacher object while calling render, the context you pass to that html file is inherited by it's children so you can access attributes of `teacher` inside the `modal.html` file without specifying it manually.